# Bind HTTP connection to specific adapter (Hint: Metered Connection)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, winhttp

Windows 8 and above has setting to make a Wi-Fi (and other) connection to be metered (and have cost attached to it, but irrelevant here). I've used [Native Wi-Fi API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706556(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WCM APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437650(v=vs.85).aspx) to find required information.

With sockets, it is possible to bind, selectively send, and ignoring incoming packets from/to the metered-connection. But, how to do this with [WinHTTP APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384257(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Some answers on StackOverflow and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/683841/how-to-bind-applications-to-specific-network-adapter) suggest using ForceBindIP, but we cannot simply use it.

If MS Windows has implemented metered connections, ideally there should be some approach to instruct WinHTTP services to not to use specific connections.

Comment: *"If MS Windows has implemented metered connections, there must be some approach to instruct WinHTTP services to not to use specific connections."* - Why?

Comment: @IInspectable, so that applications can restrict HTTP data usage on metered connections. Today, most traffic is on HTTP. Outlook, for example, is dumb, which would simply warn user if ANY network is metered. This is probably that OS doesn't have this feature. Browsers are also not able to restrict their web traffic through given adaptor.

Comment: That explains why you think there **should** be a way. It doesn't explain why you believe that there **must** be a way. I don't think that restricting HTTP data usage on metered connections would be a useful setting either. Restricting any traffic, irrespective of protocol, would be reasonable.

Comment: @IInspectable, *"Restricting any traffic, irrespective of protocol, would be reasonable"* - I agree. But I cannot get a socket-handle out of HINTERNET handle. With sockets, it is very much possible. With WinHTTP functions it is not. Technically, I am looking for solution, and not "should and musts" :)

Comment: "*I cannot get a socket-handle out of HINTERNET handle*" - actually, you can. Use `InternetQueryOption()` has an `INTERNET_OPTION_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO` option that returns an `INTERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO` struct containing the `SOCKET` handle.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for the hint. However, I found that this option is not applicable Windows 7 and above. I would try the same with WinHttp callback(s) and try to bind to specific adapter from there.

Comment: @Ajay: Thanks. I hadn't seen the note about Windows 7 dropping support for `INTERNET_OPTION_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO`.

Comment: @Ajay: I don't know if the `SOCKET` handle is provided in any WinHTTP callback, but it should be possible to hunt down manually with some work. The `INTERNET_STATUS_CONNECTED_TO_SERVER` status gives you the remote address/port pair of the server. Enumerate Windows' TCP tables looking for the same remote address/port pair belonging to your process ID. That will give you the local bound address/port pair. Enumerate your app's open kernel handles looking for TCP objects, calling `getpeername()` and `getsockname()` on them, until you find matching pairs, then you will have the `SOCKET` handle.

Comment: @Ajay: Of course, if you have multiple WinHTTP connections to the same server open at the same time, you would end up with multiple open `SOCKET` handles, and will not know which socket belongs to which WinHTTP session.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I appreciate your efforts. Please put all these details as answer (even concise). I will accept it, and will modify it so that it might be useful for others.

Comment: @Ajay: The more I think about it, what I said above is useless. While it might be possible to track down the `SOCKET` in general, it would not work until after the connection has already been established, at which time it is too late to bind the connection to a specific network.

Comment: @Ajay Were you able to figure out how to bind a HTTP request to a specific network interface ?

Comment: @Mahesh I really don't recollect anything now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither WinInet nor WinHTTP natively support what you are asking for.

You would likely have to resort to using the WinSock API `bind()` function to manually bind a WinInet/WinHTTP session socket to the desired network connection.

Prior to Windows 7, you could get a `SOCKET` handle from an `HINTERNET` handle by using `InternetQueryOption()` with the `INTERNET_OPTION_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO` option.  It fills an `INTERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO` struct with information about the connection, including the actual `SOCKET` handle.

However, this option is no longer supported in Windows 7 and later.  And while it might be possible to track down the `SOCKET` handle manually with some extra work, I don't think it would do you any good.  A socket needs to be bound with `bind()` before it attempts to connect to a server.  The relevant information provided by WinInet/WinHTTP that could be used to hunt down the `SOCKET` handle is not made available until the connect attempt is in progress.  Just prior to connecting, the info is not in the TCP routing tables yet.  And one connected, it is too late to re-bind the socket.

So I think you are out of luck on this, unless/until Microsoft exposes a new API to support binding WinInet/WinHTTP sessions, or otherwise expose access to the `SOCKET` handle again.